# Pascals Triangle

Tags: c, math

I was trying to print Pascal's Triangle using the following code. But after printing the first '1' the compiler runs into an error and I have to manually stop the execution. What might be the error in the code?

EDIT: fact function has been changed as shown with no difference whatsoever.
I'm using Codeblocks 10.05. A dialog window pops up and says that .exe has stopped working and Windows is searching for a solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void comb(int,int);
int fact(int);

int main()
{
    int n,row;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int j,k;
    for(row=1;row<=n;row++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-row;j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (k=0;k<2*row-1;k++)
        {
            comb(row-1,k);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void comb(int a,int b)
{
    if(a==0)
        printf("%d",1);
    printf("%d",fact(a)/(fact(a-b)*fact(b)));
}

int fact(int num)
 {
if(num == 1)
 {
return 1;
  }
 else return num*fact(num-1);
  }
```

Comment: Your `fact` function should always return an `int`, not just when `num!=1`.

Comment: "The compiler runs into an error". What? The compiler is only used to turn your C code into an executable. Please post the error referenced in "runs into an error".

Comment: @Michael, the fact function runs fine on its own. I have isolated everything and just tried the fact function. It properly returns the factorial

Comment: @Ozil occasionally, undefined behavior (such as failing to return a result) will accidentally give a useful (or useful-seeming) result. But that's just luck. Your `fact()` function is broken, no matter how strongly you feel that it's not. If your assumptions were all correct, you'd have no bugs, and wouldn't be here.

Comment: @Ozil You're creating an infinite recursive loop.  Your compile might have resolved it on your machine, but it's not always going to

Comment: @Avery I'm using Codeblocks 10.05. A dialog window pops up and says that <program_name>.exe has stopped working and Windows is searching for a solution.

Comment: Put the error in the question.

Comment: `comb(row-1,k);` : there are cases where you call fact (0) or  fact(negative value).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `fact(0)` will go into an infinite loop calling `fact(-1)`, then `fact(-2)`, and so on. Eventually it'll crash due to recursion running out of stack space.

How does `fact(0)` happen? when `fact(a-b)` is called when `a == b`.

This currently happens when `row == 2, k == 1`.

Comment: To fix the problem, you should have `if(num == 0) return 1;` instead of the current check against 1. You shouldn't need the special case `if` in comb() either

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes that I can see

fact function: it's infinitely recursive

improper bounds of loop which calls comb function. There are row + 1 elements in each row, not 2 * row - 1. your formula works only for the first two rows.

Try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void comb(int,int);

int fact(int);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Height: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int row  = 1; row <= n; row++)
    {
        if( row == 1)
            printf(" ");
        for(int j = 0;j < n - row; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0;k < row + 1;k++)
        {
            if ( row != 1)
                comb(row,k);
            else
            {
                printf("1");
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void comb(int a,int b)
{
    printf("%d ",fact(a)/(fact(a-b)*fact(b)));
}

int fact(int num)
{
    if(num > 1)
        return num * fact(num-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    int n,row;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int j,k;
    for(row=1;row<=n;row++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-row;j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (k=0;k<=row-1;k++)
        {
            comb(row-1,k);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void comb(int a,int b){
    printf("%d",fact(a)/(fact(a-b)*fact(b)));
}

int fact(int num){
    if(num < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return num*fact(num-1);
}
```